# Overriding archetype templates in sbt-native-packager?

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-native-packager

The 
[start-rpm-template](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/blob/master/src/main/resources/com/typesafe/sbt/packager/archetypes/systemv/start-rpm-template)
does not work with SLES 11 SP3.

Reason: Init.d/functions are not available

```
# Source function library.

. /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions
```

On SLES the functions are here:

```
/lib/lsb/init-functions
```

How can a project provide its own Archetype templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [src/main/scala/com/typesafe/sbt/packager/linux/Keys](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/sbt/packager/linux/Keys.scala#L23):

```
val linuxMakeStartScript = TaskKey[Option[File]]("makeStartScript", "Creates or discovers the start script used by this project")
val linuxStartScriptTemplate = TaskKey[URL]("linuxStartScriptTemplate", "The location of the template start script file we use for debian (upstart or init.d")
val linuxEtcDefaultTemplate = TaskKey[URL]("linuxEtcDefaultTemplate", "The location of the /etc/default/<pkg> template script.")
val linuxJavaAppStartScriptBuilder = SettingKey[JavaAppStartScriptBuilder]("linuxJavaAppStartScriptBuilder", "Responsible for loading the start scripts. Only used with archetype.java_server")
val linuxScriptReplacements = SettingKey[Seq[(String, String)]]("linuxScriptReplacements",
  """|Replacements of template parameters used in linux scripts.
       |  Default supported templates:
       |  execScript - name of the script in /usr/bin
       |  author - author of this project
       |  descr - short description
       |  chdir - execution path of the script
       |  retries - on fail, how often should a restart be tried
       |  retryTimeout - pause between retries
       |  appName - name of application
       |  appClasspath - application classpath
       |  appMainClass - main class to start
       |  daemonUser - daemon user
    """.stripMargin)
```

I would use `linuxMakeStartScript` or `linuxStartScriptTemplate` or `linuxScriptReplacements`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I used `linuxStartScriptTemplate`

Here a solution in `build.sbt` to override the template from the packager jar:

    `linuxStartScriptTemplate in Rpm := (baseDirectory.value / "src" / "rpm" / "start-rpm-template").asURL`

Comment: Could you please update my answer and accept as the solution? I'd appreciate.